# Magento Hang On Final Order Submit

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7, authorize.net

I am running Magento 1.7.0.2 and everything was running great but out of nowhere, I couldn't process any orders and was noticing that on the final order submission, my site would hang and throw a general "unable to process your order, try again" message to the user while on the backend, it would give me one of two errors:

> Blockquote
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

or

> Blockquote
>   Gateway error code E00001: An error occurred during processing. Please try again.

I am not sure why all of the sudden the mysql tables are locking up on Magento and why my orders cannot process.

Answer (score 0):

After about 8 hours, I got the site back online and it turned out there was nothing on my end to be done! All of the suggestions to mess with innodb, etc didn't work as the site processes were being killed, due to their long wait time. The issue was all being caused by our payment processor being down (Authorize.net) and so the final checkout process was hanging because authorize.net never returned an answer, which is why these errors were being thrown and the tables were being locked.

I thought I would post this here as a question/answer because I was totally down and didn't see anyone on the web talking about this issue. Hopefully, this will help others if this error is seen on their site. Thanks!